# Remove values from columns if a column contains specific string in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to remove values in the value1 and value2 column if the status column contains the string 'new'

Data

```
id  date        location    status  value1  value2  
CC  1/1/2022    ny          new     12      1   
CC  4/1/2022    ny          new     1       1   
CC  7/1/2022    ny          new     1       1   
CC  10/1/2022   ny          new     1       2   
CC  1/1/2023    ny          ok      1       2
```

Desired

```
id  date        location    status  value1  value2  
CC  1/1/2022    ny          new         
CC  4/1/2022    ny          new         
CC  7/1/2022    ny          new         
CC  10/1/2022   ny          new         
CC  1/1/2023    ny          ok      1       2
```

I do not want a NaN value, but I wish to have a blanks.
Any suggestion is appreciated

Doing

```
df.loc[(df.status == 'new')  'value1', 'value2']= np.nan
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with :

```
df.loc[(df.status == 'new'), ['value1', 'value2']] = ''
```

Comment: **"I do not want with a NaN value but wish to have blanks"**

Comment: Use '' instead of np.nan. Two single quotes no space. to assign a blank string.

Comment: Hi @BENY I tried adding more columns besides 2 and this doesn't work. Isn't the logic the same as you add more columns?

Comment: @Lynn df.loc[(df.status == 'new'), ['value1', 'value2'，'value3']] = ''